# What is a natural term for the "partial word" in a game of hangman?

Tags: single-word-requests

Halfway through a game of hangman, the piece of paper you are playing on might look something like this (omitting the partial drawing of the hanged man).

> ```
> _AN_MAN
> Guessed letters: EASTNRM
> ```

What is a natural term to use for the "partial word" `_AN_MAN`? I have tried googling, but to no avail. I am looking for a single word or short phrase that would be understood by anybody, and is less clumsy than "partial word". In my head I've been calling `_AN_MAN` the *board*, similar to how I suppose you might call a particular arrangement of chess pieces on a chess board "the board", but I do not think this would be immediately understood/considered natural.

Example sentence:

> After guessing seven letters, the _____ was `_AN_MAN`.

Comment: Not really enough to quality as an answer, so am adding as a comment. I think some play on _revealed_ might get your meaning across pretty clearly: _After guessing 7 letters, the __revealed portion__ was_ `_AN_MAN`.

Comment: I would call it a template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several word finder websites allow you to find a word based on partial information; they would list `HANGMAN`, `SANDMAN` etc. as the options for the input `_AN_MAN`.

Some of them, e.g. [this one](http://www.puzzledepot.com/wordfinder2/crossword.html) call the input a *word pattern*.

(The sites generally offer more options than necessary for Hangman; a blank in Hangman is always only one character, similar to the `?` [wildcard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wildcard).)

Comment: *pattern* is also the term used for the combined  *Regular Expression* (aka RegEx) symbols used for matching in computer programming.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

‘Answer’ is a simple word for the partial word in Hangman.

Whether ‘partial’ or ‘full’ it is still the ‘answer’, so I think you can use that term.

Meaning of answer ‘a correct response’.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/answer

Comment: I don’t agree. _AN_MAN is not an answer. Only the completed word can be an answer here.

Comment: _AN_MAN is the ‘answer so far’. It is ‘the answer’ at a certain point in the game. If the player cancels the game, it will be the only answer to ever have existed. Thus, it is ‘the answer’.